# C# or VB.NET: How to programatically change encoding format to UTF-8 of all text files in a given directory?

Tags: c#, vb.net, encoding

I am trying to loop through a directory and for ever text file that I find, convert the encoding to UTF-8 Fromat.

Comment: If you just want to get the job done, use existing tools such as `iconv`. If you want to write such a tool yourself, tell us what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: This isn't very likely to come to a good end.  The task implies that the text files are in an unknown encoding right now.  Which means you don't know how to reliably read them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) and you're pretty much done

```
DirectoryInfo DI = new DirectoryInfo("TextFiles_Path");
FileInfo[] Files = DI.GetFiles("*.txt");
foreach(FileInfo Fl in Files)
{
    StreamReader SR = Fl.OpenText(); //This opens a stream to the file **in UTF8 encoding**
    StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(Fl.FullName + ".UTF8.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate), Encoding.UTF8);
    SW.Write(SR.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Enjoy

Comment: Do you know if i need anything aside from using system.io?  i am getting errors

Comment: File[] Files = DI.GetFiles("*.txt");    Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IO.FileInfo[]' to 'System.IO.File[]'

Comment: Sorry, edited so it uses the constructor that takes an encoding as parameter

Comment: I tried the code but it didn't work, the reason is simple, the OpenText() method reads the file content as UTF-8, this is the error in the code! if the file was saved with Windows-1252 encoding and you read its contents using OpenText() then characters are interpreted in a wrong way!

Answer (score 2):

Fast and easy

```
For Each oFile In IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    IO.File.WriteAllText(oFile, IO.File.ReadAllText(oFile), Encoding.UTF8)
Next
```

Comment: Very nice quick option :) Unfortunately this doesn't work if the source file is in ANSI encoding which is the problem that brought me here. Any accented characters will become corrupted.

Comment: of course! because the ReadAllText method reads the content as UTF-8, so if you read the content of a none UTF-8 file as UTF-8 you will get a read error, saving the file after that in UTF-8 doesn't help